# How to capture data from dynamically generated widget?

Tags: flutter

How can I capture data from each of the dynamically generated ExpansionTiles and TextField?

input_attendees_screen.dart (below is how I generate the dynamic widgets)

```
List<Widget> generateExpansionTiles(int numberOfPeople) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPeople; i++) {
      Widget expansionTile =
          ExpansionTileWidget(title: 'Attendee $i', widgets: [
        TextFieldWidget(
            hintText: 'Name of Attendee $i',
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              print(newValue);
            })
      ]);
      widgets.add(expansionTile);
    }
    return widgets;
  }
```

attendee.dart (Attendee model)

```
class Attendee {
  final String name;

  Attendee(
      {required this.name});
}
```

I would like to store `newValue` from each of the dynamically generated `TextField` into their own unique `Attendee` instance. How can I achieve this? Appreciate any help here.

No idea how to solve.